# NixOS: Ensure root-level folder exists

Tags: nixos

At work we tend to keep our large code workspaces under a /scratch folder.
Is there a NixOS option to declare such a folder/file should exist?

I know about environment.etc which will setup symlink from /etc into the nix store.

Otherwise I'd have to resort to declare some systemd boot-up script, doing mkdir -p and so on - which feels ugly.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use `systemd.tmpfiles.rules`.  See its entry in docs, e.g. `man configuration.nix`.